# Personalized Search Results for Elasticsearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch, personalization

How would one go about setting up Elasticsearch so that it returns personalized results?

For example, I would want results returned to a particular user to rank higher if they clicked on a result previously, or if they "starred" that result in the past. You could also have a "hide" option that pushes results further down the ranking. From what I've seen with elasticsearch so far, it seems difficult to return different rankings to users based on that user's own dynamic data.

The solution would have to scale to thousands of users doing a dozen or so searches per day. Ideally, I would like the ranking to change in real-time, but it's not critical.

Comment: if you solved this, can you share some info? I'm trying to implement a very similar functionality, but the answer below doesn't have enough info for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Elasticsearch provides a wide variety of scoring options , but then to achieve what you have told you will need to do some additional tasks.

[Function score query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) and document [terms lookup terms filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/query-dsl-terms-query.html#query-dsl-terms-lookup) would be our tools of our choice

First create a document per user , telling the links or link ID he visited and the links he has liked. This should be housed separately as separate index. And this should be maintained by the user , as he should update and maintain this record from client side.

Now when a user hits the data index, do a function score query with filter function pointing to this fields.

In this approach , as the filter is cached , you should get decent performance too.

Comment: Vineeth, this is very similar to what I need. But my elasticsearch-fu isn't that good yet, so can you post or point me to some examples?